# Android SDK - How to play audio at reduced speed?

Tags: android, sdk, media-player

How can I play an mp3 at half speed?  I don't see any helper method in MediaPlayer class.

Answer (score 4):

The `MediaPlayer` does not provide access to the playback rate. However, `SoundPool` does. Take a look at that class and if it suits your needs, problem solved.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html